# How to unhighlight table cell while dragging

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How do we unhighlight a cell on **tap+hold+drag**. I'm using following code to change the background of a view inside the cell to give it a highlight effect. When I tap on the cell, hold and drag it should be unhighlighted.

I tried using `didUnhighlightRowAt` but it unhighlights too quickly on cell tap.

It is not long press gesture. Refer to Apple's Settings app. Press and hold any menu, it will highlight, then start to drag, it will unhighlight the cell. That's what I want to implement.

How to achieve this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.bgView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight on touch / unhighlight when scroll starts is the default behavior for table view cells.

By implementing `didHighlightRowAt` you are counter-acting that behavior.

Instead, in your cell class, implement `setHighlighted`:

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.bgView.backgroundColor = highlighted ? .red : .clear
    })
}
```